# Implementing a category tree

Tags: python, graph, tree, categories

I am implementing a continent-country relation category map
In my implementation a method `add_country()`, and as a parameter of `add_country` I provide the name of the country and continent it belongs to, for example, `add_country(Uganda, Africa)`. This adds a node Africa->Uganda.

If I pass a similar function, with the second parameter as `0`, ex. `add_country(Asia, 0)`, it should add the first parameter as a category head or parent.
The `get_country()` method should return the name of all countries belonging to that continent (or children).

So far I have made this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.children = []
        self.value = val

    def add_child(self, val):
        n = Node(val)
        self.children.append(n)

    def print_stat(self):
      print(self.children)
      print(self.value)

class CountryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.roots = []


    def add_country(self, country, parent):
      if parent == None:
        root = Node(country)
        self.roots.append(root)
      else:
        par = Node(parent)
        par.add_child(country)



    def get_country(self, parent):
      par = Node(parent)
      return par.children



map = CountryTree()
map.add_country('Asia', None)
map.add_country('China', 'Asia')
map.add_country('Russia', 'Asia')
map.get_country('Asia') #Should return China and Russia
```

But running this is returning me with an empty array.

Comment: You need to describe in more detail _how_ it is "not working".

Comment: I have updated it sir

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre], At the moment, You code causes a `NameError: name 'category' is not defined` from the `map.add_country('China', 'Asia')` call — not an empty array.

Comment: There was a small typo in question, causing this error!, 

I have rectified it,
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you want. Most of the significant changes were to the `CountryTree` class. I changed the list of continents you had into a dictionary. This makes determining if one is present easy and fast — something your `add_country()` method wasn't doing — which was one of the major things wrong with it. I also changed its name from `self.roots` to `self.continents` to be more descriptive. I also gave the `parent` argument a default value of `None` which makes providing it when adding continent nodes optional.

Another important change was to make the code follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines to make it more readable and understandable. I **strongly** suggest that you read and follow them yourself.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.children = []
        self.value = value

    def add_child(self, value):
        self.children.append(Node(value))

    def __repr__(self):
        classname = type(self).__name__
        return (f'{classname}({self.value!r}, {self.children})' if self.children else
                f'{classname}({self.value!r})')

    def print_stat(self):
        print(self.children)
        print(self.value)


class CountryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.continents = {}  # Dictionary mapping continents to countries.

    def add_country(self, country, parent=None):
        if not parent:  # Adding a continent?
            continent = country
            self.continents[continent] = Node(continent)
        else:  # Adding a country to a continent.
            continent = self.continents.get(parent, None)
            if not continent:
                raise KeyError(f'No continent named {parent} exists')
            continent.add_child(country)

    def get_country(self, parent):
        continent = self.continents.get(parent, None)
        if not continent:
            raise KeyError(f'No continent named {parent} exists')
        return continent.children


map = CountryTree()
map.add_country('Asia')
map.add_country('China', 'Asia')
map.add_country('Russia', 'Asia')
result = map.get_country('Asia') # Should return China and Russia
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[Node('China'), Node('Russia')]
```